# Xlib control keyboard events

Tags: python, linux, xlib

How does one simulate keyboard key presses in python (Xlib)
I have been using Xlib-python for simulating mouse pointer events such as movements and clicks. But I haven't been able to find enough help for doing a similar thing for keyboard presses.

Preferred platform : python on linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One uses [xtest](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xtest/1.0) for this. As an added bonus, it also handles pointer event injection.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert on Xlib, but managed to piece together this code for the PyAutoGUI module. Here's the minimum viable example that can simulate a `keyDown()` and `keyUp()` for a keyboard key:

```
# You must run `pip3 install python3-xlib` to get the Xlib modules.

import os

from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X
from Xlib.ext.xtest import fake_input
import Xlib.XK

_display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])

# Create the keyboard mapping.
KEY_NAMES = ['\t', '\n', '\r', ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(',
     ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
     '8', '9', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '\\', ']', '^', '_', '`',
     'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
     'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '{', '|', '}', '~',
     'accept', 'add', 'alt', 'altleft', 'altright', 'apps', 'backspace',
     'browserback', 'browserfavorites', 'browserforward', 'browserhome',
     'browserrefresh', 'browsersearch', 'browserstop', 'capslock', 'clear',
     'convert', 'ctrl', 'ctrlleft', 'ctrlright', 'decimal', 'del', 'delete',
     'divide', 'down', 'end', 'enter', 'esc', 'escape', 'execute', 'f1', 'f10',
     'f11', 'f12', 'f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'f18', 'f19', 'f2', 'f20',
     'f21', 'f22', 'f23', 'f24', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9',
     'final', 'fn', 'hanguel', 'hangul', 'hanja', 'help', 'home', 'insert', 'junja',
     'kana', 'kanji', 'launchapp1', 'launchapp2', 'launchmail',
     'launchmediaselect', 'left', 'modechange', 'multiply', 'nexttrack',
     'nonconvert', 'num0', 'num1', 'num2', 'num3', 'num4', 'num5', 'num6',
     'num7', 'num8', 'num9', 'numlock', 'pagedown', 'pageup', 'pause', 'pgdn',
     'pgup', 'playpause', 'prevtrack', 'print', 'printscreen', 'prntscrn',
     'prtsc', 'prtscr', 'return', 'right', 'scrolllock', 'select', 'separator',
     'shift', 'shiftleft', 'shiftright', 'sleep', 'space', 'stop', 'subtract', 'tab',
     'up', 'volumedown', 'volumemute', 'volumeup', 'win', 'winleft', 'winright', 'yen',
     'command', 'option', 'optionleft', 'optionright']

keyboardMapping = dict([(key, None) for key in KEY_NAMES])
keyboardMapping.update({
    'backspace':         _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('BackSpace')),
    '\b':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('BackSpace')),
    'tab':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Tab')),
    'enter':             _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Return')),
    'return':            _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Return')),
    'shift':             _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Shift_L')),
    'ctrl':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Control_L')),
    'alt':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Alt_L')),
    'pause':             _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Pause')),
    'capslock':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Caps_Lock')),
    'esc':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Escape')),
    'escape':            _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Escape')),
    'pgup':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Page_Up')),
    'pgdn':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Page_Down')),
    'pageup':            _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Page_Up')),
    'pagedown':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Page_Down')),
    'end':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('End')),
    'home':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Home')),
    'left':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Left')),
    'up':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Up')),
    'right':             _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Right')),
    'down':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Down')),
    'select':            _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Select')),
    'print':             _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Print')),
    'execute':           _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Execute')),
    'prtsc':             _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Print')),
    'prtscr':            _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Print')),
    'prntscrn':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Print')),
    'printscreen':       _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Print')),
    'insert':            _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Insert')),
    'del':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Delete')),
    'delete':            _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Delete')),
    'help':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Help')),
    'winleft':           _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Super_L')),
    'winright':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Super_R')),
    'apps':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Super_L')),
    'num0':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_0')),
    'num1':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_1')),
    'num2':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_2')),
    'num3':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_3')),
    'num4':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_4')),
    'num5':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_5')),
    'num6':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_6')),
    'num7':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_7')),
    'num8':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_8')),
    'num9':              _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_9')),
    'multiply':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_Multiply')),
    'add':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_Add')),
    'separator':         _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_Separator')),
    'subtract':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_Subtract')),
    'decimal':           _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_Decimal')),
    'divide':            _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('KP_Divide')),
    'f1':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F1')),
    'f2':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F2')),
    'f3':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F3')),
    'f4':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F4')),
    'f5':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F5')),
    'f6':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F6')),
    'f7':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F7')),
    'f8':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F8')),
    'f9':                _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F9')),
    'f10':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F10')),
    'f11':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F11')),
    'f12':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F12')),
    'f13':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F13')),
    'f14':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F14')),
    'f15':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F15')),
    'f16':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F16')),
    'f17':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F17')),
    'f18':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F18')),
    'f19':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F19')),
    'f20':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F20')),
    'f21':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F21')),
    'f22':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F22')),
    'f23':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F23')),
    'f24':               _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('F24')),
    'numlock':           _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Num_Lock')),
    'scrolllock':        _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Scroll_Lock')),
    'shiftleft':         _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Shift_L')),
    'shiftright':        _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Shift_R')),
    'ctrlleft':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Control_L')),
    'ctrlright':         _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Control_R')),
    'altleft':           _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Alt_L')),
    'altright':          _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Alt_R')),
    # These are added because unlike a-zA-Z0-9, the single characters do not have a
    ' ': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('space')),
    'space': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('space')),
    '\t': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Tab')),
    '\n': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Return')),  # for some reason this needs to be cr, not lf
    '\r': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Return')),
    '\e': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('Escape')),
    '!': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('exclam')),
    '#': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('numbersign')),
    '%': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('percent')),
    '$': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('dollar')),
    '&': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('ampersand')),
    '"': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('quotedbl')),
    "'": _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('apostrophe')),
    '(': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('parenleft')),
    ')': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('parenright')),
    '*': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('asterisk')),
    '=': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('equal')),
    '+': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('plus')),
    ',': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('comma')),
    '-': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('minus')),
    '.': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('period')),
    '/': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('slash')),
    ':': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('colon')),
    ';': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('semicolon')),
    '<': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('less')),
    '>': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('greater')),
    '?': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('question')),
    '@': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('at')),
    '[': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('bracketleft')),
    ']': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('bracketright')),
    '\\': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('backslash')),
    '^': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('asciicircum')),
    '_': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('underscore')),
    '`': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('grave')),
    '{': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('braceleft')),
    '|': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('bar')),
    '}': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('braceright')),
    '~': _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym('asciitilde')),
})

for c in """abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890""":
    keyboardMapping[c] = _display.keysym_to_keycode(Xlib.XK.string_to_keysym(c))



def isShiftCharacter(character):
    """Returns True if the key character is uppercase or shifted."""
    return character.isupper() or character in '~!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:"<>?'


def keyDown(key):
    """Performs a keyboard key press without the release. This will put that
    key in a held down state.

    NOTE: For some reason, this does not seem to cause key repeats like would
    happen if a keyboard key was held down on a text field.

    Args:
      key (str): The key to be pressed down. The valid names are listed in
      pyautogui.KEY_NAMES.

    Returns:
      None
    """
    if key not in keyboardMapping or keyboardMapping[key] is None:
        return

    if type(key) == int:
        fake_input(_display, X.KeyPress, key)
        _display.sync()
        return

    needsShift = isShiftCharacter(key)
    if needsShift:
        fake_input(_display, X.KeyPress, keyboardMapping['shift'])

    fake_input(_display, X.KeyPress, keyboardMapping[key])

    if needsShift:
        fake_input(_display, X.KeyRelease, keyboardMapping['shift'])
    _display.sync()


def keyUp(key):
    """Performs a keyboard key release (without the press down beforehand).

    Args:
      key (str): The key to be released up. The valid names are listed in
      KEY_NAMES.

    Returns:
      None
    """

    """
    Release a given character key. Also works with character keycodes as
    integers, but not keysyms.
    """
    if key not in keyboardMapping or keyboardMapping[key] is None:
        return

    if type(key) == int:
        keycode = key
    else:
        keycode = keyboardMapping[key]

    fake_input(_display, X.KeyRelease, keycode)
    _display.sync()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any Windows users stumble across this question:

<s>https://gist.github.com/Audionautics/2906125</s>

Link may be broken, here is a similar Python code block that I have used to build off of:

```
import time
import win32api, win32con

VK_CODE = {'left_arrow':0x25,
           'spacebar':0x20,
           'right_arrow':0x27}

def press(x):
    win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[x], 0,0,0)
    win32api.keybd_event(VK_CODE[x],0 ,win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP ,0)

def play():
    time.sleep(1)
    s = time.time()
    while time.time() - s < 15:
        press("left_arrow")
        press("right_arrow")
        press("left_arrow")
        press("right_arrow")
        press('spacebar')  

play()
```

Credit goes to:

[chriskieh on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/chriskiehl/3287367)